# Strange steps measurement in iphone

Tags: iphone, health.app

Does someone have an explanation for this strange step measurement which is happening in my iPhone?

[image]

As you can see from the screenshot here reported, for some days in this month the steps counted were exactly the same (I have noticed that this happens frequently).

Clearly, it is impossible that the phone counts the same number of steps for consecutive days. I think this may be an average value computed due to missing data.

I checked the actual amount of steps for those days and it is always the same fixed value.

Is it normal? Can I avoid this to happen?

Comment: Is it possible the actual amount of steps was different but due to the relatively inaccurate scale, only appears as if they are equal? For example, 10100, 10050, 9950.

Comment: No, I checked positioning the finger in the exact day and the value is equal in all those days.

Comment: Try tapping on each date, one at a time, in the regular view. I've noticed since iOS 12 that it often fails to update at all unless I do that - though I've not tested that across several days

Comment: Ah, bug confirmed; unfortunately if you don't manually do that "often enough" [I can't test more accurately] then that 'fake history' becomes permanent.

Comment: @Tetsujin what do you mean? Is a bug unsolved reported somewhere?

Comment: I have no way to know if it has been reported, but yes, it's a bug if more than one person can reproduce the same unwanted effect. You'd need to report it on  https://bugreport.apple.com

Comment: @Tetsujin ok. And this happened also in your iPhone? how have you confirmed?

Comment: I have confirmed it by following the same procedure & arriving at the same result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue fund is in fact a bug. I have reported it on [bugreport.apple.com](http://bugreport.apple.com)

I guess now, they are taking care of the problem...