# Why is the steps data in Health app all the same on everyday?

Tags: ios, health.app

I have noticed that the steps count on my iPhone’s Heath app somehow becomes the same on everyday.

I don’t really know when it will just “normalise” the count to become the same but it somehow does that after every few days later.

[image: Step count are all the same on everyday for weird reasons]

The count for the current day usually still looks alright, but the counts for the past day all look the same.

I think this probably happened after I upgraded my iOS to version 12.0.1. I have not upgraded past iOS 12.0.1

Does anyone have this issue and how can I fix it?

**Update:**
Chances are a large chunk of my data in the past since I’ve upgraded to iOS12 are already bad. I’ve updated my iOS to the most recent version. I’ll have to monitor and see how things go in the next week days.

Comment: Precisely what iOS? I haven't seen this in the last few point releases, but it was a definite bug early on - see https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/340831/strange-steps-measurement-in-iphone

Comment: @Tetsujin I’m on iOS12.0.1.

Comment: Then the fix is to update. Looking back at my timeline it seems to have stopped misbehaving around mid/late Oct [which is between 12.0.1 & 12.1 iirc]

Comment: @Tetsujin Alright, I’m going to try upgrading my iOS and report back on whether that is going to fix the issue. Thanks!

Comment: Wish you luck - I don't think it can backdate to fix existing 'bad' data, just fix it going forward.

Comment: @Tetsujin Just curious though, is this a known issue with my version of iOS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First thing to do is establish if the underlying data is wrong or the chart is wrong.

Tap to the month (top of your picture) and the compare a few days with what **Show all data** reveals for the daily summaries.

- [Strange steps measurement in iphone](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/340831/strange-steps-measurement-in-iphone)

The month view is shown in the thread linked above.

[image]

[image]

Either way, I would back up your health data to iTunes with a passphrase to encrypt the backup and to iCloud so you have two good backups before you try to upgrade to the latest iOS.

If the data is bad, you’ll have to look at the sources of step data and possibly upgrade the iOS / wait for a bug fix from Apple.

If it’s just the graph, updating iOS and bug report to Apple is likely the fix.